# Table data overflows after table size reduced

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello beautiful people of SO. Hope you're having a good day. So I got this weird issue which I'm unable to solve.

I have a table of data. I want it to be at a collapsed state with scroll at first then if the button is pressed then the size will increase based on the table rows inside. By that I mean the height will be auto.

An example would be the table here on right: [example](https://ethplorer.io/address/0x7bbcab2bb3cb157b90d2393b985088bb3c560774)

At this moment, the div shrinks but the data is overflowing out.

Here's the pen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zakero/full/WNxqeaE)

Here's the snippet:

```js
const expandCollapseBtn = $('#expand-collapse-btn');

$(expandCollapseBtn).click((e) => {
    const divHeight = $(".data-container").height();

    if ( divHeight > 400 ) {
        $(".data-container").animate({"height": "200px"}, 100);
    }
    else if ($(".data-container").css("height") == "200px") {
        $(".data-container").animate({"height": "400px"}, 100);
    }
});
```

```css
.data-container {
    min-height: 45px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    position: relative;
}


.data-container .bg-light {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
    border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.data-container h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section .data-container .table-container .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    line-height: 15px;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    width: 2%;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:last-child {
    padding-left: 6px;
    width: 49%;
}

.data-container .table-container table td {
    padding: 5px 18px 5px 20px;
}

.data-container .table-container a {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.data-container .table-container tr {
    height: 45px;
}

#flag-image {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}


.data-container button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #343a40;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-container w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="card-header bg-light text-center pt-3 pb-3">
          <h2>
              Total: $200
          </h2> 
      </div>

      <div class="table-container">
          <table class="table-striped w-100">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>5</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>6</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>7</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                     <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>8</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>9</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>10</td>
                      <td>:</td>
                      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
      <button id="expand-collapse-btn">expand &darr;</button>
  </div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `overflow-y: scroll;` to `.data-container` . Though, since the "expand" button is also placed inside this `div`, it will only appear near the bottom when the `div` is scrolled to the end. If you want the button to remain static, you can apply the height restriction and scroll on `.table-container` instead

Comment: I modified your code a bit and it seems to be working as intended.
It also helps to animate `max-heght` instead of `height`
https://codepen.io/luka-kiria/pen/rNLEajM

Comment: hey it works fine but there's one small issue. You hardcoded the expanded height to be 1000px. But I want it to be flexible as I don't know the exact height. It could be shorter or longer than that. I tried putting auto in there but it kind of froze. any suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't animate height unless you give it an exact value. You can set it to a very high value, which will result in a very fast animation. A better way would be to give it a smaller max-height first and after a delay set it to auto.

Answer (score 0):

A little change to your script worked.

And also added `overflow: scroll` css to your `data-container`

```js
const expandCollapseBtn = $('#expand-collapse-btn');

$(expandCollapseBtn).click((e) => {
  const divHeight = $(".data-container").height();
  if (divHeight >= 400) {
    $(".data-container").animate({
      "height": "200px"
    }, 100);
  } else if (divHeight <= 200) {
    $(".data-container").animate({
      "height": "400px"
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```css
.data-container {
  min-height: 45px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.data-container .bg-light {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.data-container h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section .data-container .table-container .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(2n+1)>td {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:first-child {
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  width: 2%;
}

.data-container .table-container table tr td:last-child {
  padding-left: 6px;
  width: 49%;
}

.data-container .table-container table td {
  padding: 5px 18px 5px 20px;
}

.data-container .table-container a {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.data-container .table-container tr {
  height: 45px;
}

#flag-image {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.data-container button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #343a40;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-container w-75 m-auto">
  <div class="card-header bg-light text-center pt-3 pb-3">
    <h2>
      Total: $200
    </h2>
  </div>

  <div class="table-container">
    <table class="table-striped w-100">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="expand-collapse-btn">expand &darr;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It has scroll in both states. I want the scroll to be only their in the default(collapsed) state. Not in expanded state.